# Access column after reading .csv file with fread

Tags: r, csv, data.table, fread, read.csv

when I read a .csv file with **read.csv** like this

```
df1 <- read.csv("a.csv")
```

and I access a single column like this

```
df1[,1]
```

I get the expected column vector.

---

But in contrast, if i read the .csv with **fread** (from the library data.table)

```
df2 <- fread("a.csv")
```

and access a single column

```
df2[,1]
```

It just returns

> 1

Can somebody explain, why I can't access the column vector by its index, when I read the csv with fread?

Comment: Because you need to read the [tuorial](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started). In other words, `fread` in not some base R function rather coming from the `data.table` package (which you failed to mention) and creates a `data.table` objects which has it's own syntax.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer.

Comment: In other words use `df2[, 2, with = FALSE]` or `df2[[1]]` or pass the (unquoted) column name instead the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `?fread` in `data.table`, you will find a parameter `data.table`:

> data.table     TRUE returns a data.table. FALSE returns a data.frame.

By default, `data.table` is `TRUE`, hence a data.table is created.

If you prefer the `df2[,1]` style, using:

```
df2 <- fread("a.csv",data.table=FALSE)
```